# Ansible: how to register variable in uri module?

Tags: ansible, uri

This is my code or checking wheter the website is valid and running:

```
  - hosts: master
    become: true
    tasks:
    - name: "Checking server availibility"
      uri:
        url: http://www.google.pl
        timeout: 5
      register: command_result
      ignore_errors: yes

    - debug: msg= "{{ command_result }}"
```

So `command_result` variable always returns this output regardless of the website availability:

```
ok: [Centos.v1] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
```

I would like to know if the first task was succesful or not but i can't do that when the output of registered variable is always the same.

How to setup my variable properly to read the return code?
and also 
Is there some other way to check if an error occured in the previous task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with registering.

Remove the space character after `msg=`, otherwise you pass an empty string to the `debug` module and it prints `Hello World!` as a result (its default behaviour).

Better yet, use `var` parameter and YAML syntax:

```
- debug:
    var: command_result
```